# How many copies of $S_5$ is there in $S_6$

Tags: permutations

By simple permutations and by fixing one element say $f(6)=6$,we can get a copy of $S_5$ in $S_6$ . Similarly we can obtain 6 different copies , can I obtain a 7th copy?

Comment: By Copy  I mean $S_5$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of  $S_6$ obtained by fixing one element and permutating the others

Comment: Then it is a simple matter of counting the number of ways we can choose k out of n elements to fix. So its a simple combination to see the number of subgroups of size k are isomorphic to $S_k$

Comment: @DonThousand $S_6$ has outer automorphisms which, if applied to one of the "normal" copies of $S_5$ (fixing a point), yields an "exotic" copy of $S_5$ (does not fix a point).

Comment: @Ted can you elaborate,  I didn't get it